# Usage of @code_warntype in Julia

Tags: types, julia

When trying to write type-stable code, examining using `@code_warntype`, should I only worry about not having any `Any` or `Union` in the variables section or I should also check the body section?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your version of julia, `@code_warntype` can sometimes flag certain expressions that are harmless. With a little bit of practice you can easily recognize these expressions (e.g., they often have to do with module/name lookup).

The easy path, as Reza says, is to look at the variables section and the function's return-type; if you don't see any type-uncertain quantities (either `Any` or `Union`s) you probably have nothing to worry about. If you want to dig deeper, start trying to make sense of the body expressions that it's flagging. For learning, one useful thing to do is compare the results against those obtained with `track-allocation`, since true type instability is associated with memory allocation.

However, I think the issues with `@code_warntype` have been fixed on current master, so in any case the next release of julia should make it easier to interpret.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is that I use Jupyter, so to use `track-allocation` I'd have to switch to the REPL...

Comment: You can also use the profiler; in ProfileView, statements that allocate a lot tend to be associated with garbage collection, and lines that trigger garbage collection are highlighted in red.

Answer (score 5):

Normally it's not necessary to search **body** part for more so-called **non-leaf** types, because the `code_warntype` main task is to do this job for you, ([check source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/interactiveutil.jl#L222)). But the body part have more informations about where and how this **non-leaf**s have been used.

References:

1. [`code_warntype(f, types)`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#Base.code_warntype) in documentation.
2. [`code_warntype(f, types)`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/interactiveutil.jl#L222) source.

Comment: Even when I can see some `Any`s in the body?

Answer (score 0):

@code_warntype also reports 'Core.NewVarNode' objects against some variables. I believe, without any measures taken, these message about additional memory allocations and aren't welcomed in inner loops, where frequent memory allocations can spawn.
I usually examine code only if variable appear as Union{} in listing of variables in output of type inference. This means, error will take place on execution before the variable will attain a value.