# Interpreting Body expression from @code_warntype

Tags: julia

If we run:

```
@code_warntype deepcopy(rand(2))
```

at the Julia REPL, the output contains flagged values in the Body expression. Specifically, the two `Any` at the end of:

```
Body:
  begin  # deepcopy.jl, line 8:
      GenSym(0) = (Base.Array)(Base.Any,32)::Array{Any,1}
      return (Base.deepcopy_internal)(x::Array{Float64,1},$(Expr(:new, :((top(getfield))(Base,:ObjectIdDict)::Type{ObjectIdDict}), GenSym(0))))::Any
  end::Any
```

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930702/usage-of-code-warntype-in-julia) that we usually don't need to worry about flagged values in the Body expression if our primary concern is type instability. So instead, my question is this:

Why does a fairly simple function from `Base` generate *any* flagged values in `@code_warntype`? I'm sure there are good reasons, but I am new at interpreting the output from `@code_warntype`, and had some trouble understanding the discussion of the Body expression from the official docs.

Comment: I edited that answer so that it clarifies that return type is also something to worry about.

Comment: @tholy Understood. Many thanks. I also can see that you're responsible for the fix, so thanks for that too (I use `deepcopy` reasonably often) :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of a situation where type inference is unable to figure out the return type of a function. (Note the `::Any` on the return value!) It **is** a problem, not because the computation itself will be slower because of type instability, but because the return type cannot be inferred, and so future computations using the return type will suffer from type instability.

You can see this effect by looking at allocations below:

```
julia> function f()
         y = rand(10)
         @time y[1] + y[10]
         z = deepcopy(y)
         @time z[1] + z[10]
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f();  # ignore output here on first compile

julia> f();
  0.000000 seconds
  0.000002 seconds (3 allocations: 48 bytes)
```

Note that the second operations requires allocations and takes time, because unboxing and dynamic dispatch are involved.

In the current nightly build of what will become 0.5 (which will likely be released within a few months), this has been [fixed](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/10d05935dca01d0f6683ebd086e9e96e300d827b). Thus

```
julia> @code_warntype deepcopy(rand(2))
Variables:
  #self#::Base.#deepcopy
  x::Array{Float64,1}

Body:
  begin  # deepcopy.jl, line 8:
      # meta: location dict.jl Type # dict.jl, line 338:
      SSAValue(1) = (Core.ccall)(:jl_alloc_array_1d,(Core.apply_type)(Core.Array,Any,1)::Type{Array{Any,1}},(Core.svec)(Core.Any,Core.Int)::SimpleVector,Array{Any,1},0,32,0)::Array{Any,1}
      # meta: pop location
      return (Core.typeassert)((Base.deepcopy_internal)(x::Array{Float64,1},$(Expr(:new, :(Base.ObjectIdDict), SSAValue(1))))::Any,Array{Float64,1})::Array{Float64,1}
  end::Array{Float64,1}
```

which has no type instability, and

```
julia> f()
  0.000000 seconds
  0.000000 seconds
```

which has no dynamic dispatch and no allocations.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your answer is very interesting! So just by chance I happened to pick a function from `Base` with type instability... One quick clarification: What is the difference between the `Any` at the end of the `return` line in my question, and the `Any` in the following line after the `end` (ie `end::Any`)? Both are flagged (red font) at the REPL (in v0.4) - do both refer to the return type?

Comment: @ColinTBowers In this example, both refer to the return type, because the function only returns in one place. Some functions have multiple locations that they can return from, and for those functions, the `Any` after the end warns about a return type instability even if each individual return statement is fine.

Comment: Understood. I often write functions with multiple return locations. Thanks again.